# Trick to loop/autorefresh docker ps view like top/htop in bash

Tags: bash, docker, htop

Is it possible - and if yes, how - to have a self-refreshing view of current Docker containers printed by "docker ps" alike top/htop utilities?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use `watch`:

```
watch docker ps
```

See [`man watch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch)

Comment: I had to install watch with brew first: `brew install watch`. Thanks!

Comment: it complains when I try to pass arguments like --format

Comment: Use quotes: https://superuser.com/questions/276701/using-the-watch-command-with-an-argument-that-contains-quotes

Comment: unfortunately still fails: `watch "docker stats --format 'table {{.Names}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Status}}'" `

Comment: Your --format didn't work for me. probably a version issue. But check this for example: `watch 'docker stats --no-stream --format "table {{.Container}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}"'
`

Comment: When you have [two levels of nesting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23349/), prefer to use single quotes around the outer command, e.g., `watch 'sudo docker ps --format "table {{.Names}}\t{{.Status}}"'`.

Comment: use `watch -d -n 10 docker ps` to highlight changes (`-d`) and update only every 10 seconds (`-n 10`).

Answer (score 31):

Few options:

1. You can try command `docker stats`, which will give you some details about current running containers id, cpu%, memory etc. Something similar to `top/htop` which you asked for.
2. Command `docker top CONTAINER [ps OPTIONS]` : It displays the running processes of a container.
3. There are also some applications available which gives nice view of your docker ecosystem. Eg- [Kitematic](https://kitematic.com/), [Kevana](https://github.com/kevana/ui-for-docker)

Comment: Should be the correct answer to me since it does not require additional tool (like `watch`)

Answer (score 5):

As alternative to watch, there is an alias shown to loop docker stats (watch: might not be always available by default)

This creates a bash alias "ds"

```
alias ds='while true; do TEXT=$(docker stats --no-stream $(docker ps --format={{.Names}})); sleep 0.1; clear; echo "$TEXT"; done'
```

from: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20973